# Probability 3 couples out of 6 are paired around table

Tags: probability, combinations

Six couples sit around table .
Find # ways exactly  3 couples 
Out of the six 
sit next to each other . Also find
probability. Please generalize
for exactly 0,1,2,3 ..6 etc couples.
are paired out of six total couples
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Know how to solve for zero pairs using inclusion exclusion and all six pairs

Comment: Do you know how many ways to pick three couples out of six?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Pick 3 couples out of 6 is 6x5x4 /6  if order does not matter -ie a combination problem..

Comment: Treat the 3 couples as being indivuals instead. That is, first find the number of ways 3 couples and 3 singles can sit with none of the couples adjacent. Then consider how many ways to choose 3 couples out of 6 couples, and who sits on which side for the adjacent couples.